# Fastest way of evaluating expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, expression, eval, mex

Inputs:

- arbitrary logical vectors (~2M elements): `i1,i2,...,in`
- arbitrary logical expression: eg. `"or(and(not(i1),i2),xor(i3,i4))"`

Output:

- resulting logical vector o `o=eval("or(and(not(i1),i2),xor(i3,i4))")`

Is there any faster way than simulating Matlab's eval function in MEX function? Would the MEX eval be actually faster than native eval? If yes, how many times?

Comment: If you're constraining the expressions to only a very limited subset of operations, then you could potentially create a much faster evaluator.

Comment: There will be only logical operations - and, or, not, nor, nand, xor, xnor.

Comment: And expression is arbitrary combination of them (max depth of expression is, let's say, 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented eval as a MEX function. I tested it on random expressions of depth 4. My MEX eval is 2x faster than Matlab native eval (15.1s vs 31.4s, 1000 iterations)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote:

```
i1 = randi([0,1],1,10^6);
i2 = randi([0,1],1,10^6);
i3 = randi([0,1],1,10^6);
i4 = randi([0,1],1,10^6);
```

(yes, these vectors only have 1M elements, not 2M)

then

```
tic,or(and(not(i1),i2),xor(i3,i4)); toc
```

which gave

```
Elapsed time is 0.047936 seconds.
```

I think you'll struggle to get a result faster using a MEX function; my gut feeling is that the MEX routine will still be waking up when the pure Matlab solution has put its feet up and cracked open a cold beer.

But I look forward to being proved wrong as I so often am.

Comment: OP problem is to evaluate arbitrary expression read from a file not to evaluate *this* particular one